# Configure Oracle 19c to manually start up

Tags: oracle

I installed Windows 10 on my Lenovo T540p laptop. Nothing special of course. I work as a developer, so I also installed Visual Studio 2019, SQL Server 2019 and Oracle 19 c.

Now, most of my work is done on SQL Server, but I do have 1 or 2 clients which use Oracle, requiring me to have a working Oracle instance on my machine.

But... I only need it like 10% of the time, so ideally I would like to configure the Oracle services so I can manually start them when I need it.

Been playing around with this in the past, but it appears simply putting the services on manual isn't enough.

Googling this question gave me a couple of ideas on how to manually start up a db, but besides 1 question here I didn't actually found anything (even partialy) usable. Anyone here who can tell me how to best pull this off?

Comment: Setting the services for manual should do it.  So exactly what did you do and how did you determine that it "wasn't enough".

Comment: When I restarted the services I couldn't connect to the local database. Perhaps there's a certain order

Comment: There are two key services - the listener ORA...TNSListener and then the database server OracleYOURDB. The listener service can be left auto (it uses barely any resource) and then having the database service manuual (and clicking Start) should be fine